# PHP PDO: How to show affected rows of UPDATE together with results of SELECT with a procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, procedure

I have a procedure with a mix of `SELECT` commands and `UPDATE` commands. Using PHP and PDO, for each query, I want to see either the results or the affected rows; however, this doesn't work for `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` queries (unless they are the only query in the procedure). I am able to retrieve the results from the `SELECT` commands using `$stmt->nextRowset();` however, I cannot retrieve the total number of records that have been updated, deleted, or inserted. How can I retrieve the affected rows?

Here is my PHP code:

```
$stmt = $connection->query($query);

do {
    // updates the counter for each procedure query
    $j++;

    // gets the total rows from each rowset
    $totalRows = $stmt->rowCount();
    $data = getColumnData($connection, $stmt);

    // checks if any data was returned
    if (!$data) {
        $rowText = $totalRows == 1 ? "row was" : "rows were";
        $queryData .= $totalRows != 0 ? "<p><label>Procedure Query {$j}</label></p><p class='success'>A total of {$totalRows} {$rowText} affected!</p>" :"<p><label>Procedure Query {$j}</label></p><p><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> No results were returned! Check the query outside the procedure.</p>";

    // displays the rows affected for other queries
    } else {
        $queryData .= "<p><label>Procedure Query {$j}</label></p><p class='success'>A total of {$totalRows} rows were returned!</p>{$data}";
    }
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());
```

Here is a sample procedure that I quickly wrote up to demonstrate what the procedure looks like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_orders(IN vDate Date)
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  FROM `order`;

  UPDATE `order`
  SET `order_date` = vDate;

  SELECT *
  FROM `order`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL get_orders(Curdate() - 1);
```

This is the output but as you can see there is a missing result for the `UPDATE` between queries one and two:
[image]

Comment: Stop trying to do it in a stored procedures. They are fiddly and painful. Forget they exist for a few years. MySQL and PDO work fine without it.

Comment: This would be vastly simpler if you implemented it as just straight-up queries through PDO. Stored procedures only over-complicate things.

Comment: `UPDATE` queries don't return result sets. Only queries that look up data (e.g. `SELECT`) return results.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! @danblack and @tadman I am building a teaching tool and already have everything working for running these queries individually, but I also want to teach my students how to use procedures for when they are in the work force. This is why I want to get this working. @Barmar I understand that `UPDATE` queries don't return result sets. I was wondering if there is something I need to change so that I can return result sets for `SELECT` queries and affected rows for `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` queries. Also, this procedure is a basic example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please don't teach your students stored procedures. They aren't used by the majority of the work force. They waste an extra ordinary amount of time for no benefit. I'd much rather a graduate that new some basics of how indexes work. Or how JOINs work.

Comment: @danblack Thanks for the feedback. I spend most of the time teaching JOINs and queries. I only teach procedures so they know what a procedure looks like when they see it. However, given your feedback, I may reconsider teaching them at all.